# Visual Studio move project to a different folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I move a project to a different folder in Visual Studio? I am used to this structure in my projects.

```
-- app
---- Project.Something
---- Project.SomethingElse
```

I want to rename the whole namespace SomethingElse to SomethingNew, what's the best way to do that (without manually going into .sln file)?

Comment: Are you using TFS as your source control provider?

Comment: Do you want to rename just the folder or the whole project?

Comment: Project, folder and namespace(s).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Remove the project from your solution by right-clicking it in the Solution Explorer window and choosing Remove.  Move the entire project folder, including subdirectories wherever you want it to go.  Add the project back to your solution.

Namespace names is something completely different, just edit the source code.

Comment: That's what I did, but I thought there is a way to do all that without removing the whole project, which makes me then re-add all the dependencies.

Comment: Unload all the dependent projects from the solution, before removing the project you want to move. That way, they don't detect the removal and the project references stay intact. After you move the project and re-add it to the solution, you can load the dependent projects again.

Comment: Don't forget that deleting a file in TFS, and then reimporting it back into TFS in another directory location or project, causes the file change history to be deleted.

Comment: i want to do it without it losing history of changes so i can still do comparisons when i want to.

Comment: Short and slick :+1:

Answer (score 223):

I tried the suggestion to remove and re-add the project, but then fixing up dependencies can be a pain.

I use this approach:

1. Move the project folder.

   - If the project is in source control, do the move using source control commands.
2. Edit the solution file in a text editor. There should be only one path that you need to change.

Comment: Definitely easier! But, after I move and edit the solution using the text edit, the solution file shows down below like a regular text file. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: "If the project is in source control, do the move using source control commands." .. Can you explain how to do this ?

Comment: @AnishV For examaple, if you use Git, type `git mv ...` instead of `mv ...`. See `git-mv` documentation for more info.

Comment: In the .csproj file you need to update the SolutionDir property, as well as fix all the paths for project references and nuget package locations. In the .sln file all you need to do is update the path to the project.

Comment: This has worked for me. The only 'trick' was I had to change the .sln file so it wasn't readonly to edit it and then mark it as readonly again for safety purposes.

Comment: It worked for me as well. I had to rebuild the VB project and it worked :)

Comment: If you are moving the folder up or down the folder hierarchy, there will be additional changes to make. For example, if you move 'foo\bar' to 'bar', you need to remove the 'Project' entry and the 'GlobalSection(NestedProjects)' entry for foo in the solution file.

Comment: I moved using TFS, but I couldn't get the solution file to play nicely until I checked in the folder moves in TFS.  I then blew away the whole branches and got latest.  After this, I was able to update the sln paths (there were four paths per project, one at top and three at the bottom).

Answer (score 53):

1. Close your solution in VS2012
2. Move your project to the new location
3. Open your solution
4. Select the project that failed to load
5. In the Properties tool window, there an editable “File path” entry that allows you to select the new project location
6. Set the new path
7. Right click on the project and click reload

Comment: This works extremely well and would seem to be the fastest and easiest way, the other much-higher voted answers notwithstanding. There is an article on it here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/06/30/solution-files-change-project-directory-location.aspx

Comment: @MikeRosenblum The link is broken, the new link is http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/solution-files-change-project-directory-location/

Comment: Does not work in VS2012. The linked article also only mentions VS2010.

Comment: Worked fine for me in VS2010 including all my references except 1 which I had to re-add.

Comment: @Vasanth In Visual Studio 2019 you need to manually edit the .sln file to locate the project; and possibly (probably) the .csproj file too to refererence the correct location of any nuget packages.

Comment: I achieved it by opening the .sln file in normal text editor like notepad or notepad++ and changing the path of specific project there. After many trial and error, this worked fine for me.

Comment: This seems very dated and no longer an option 2019 or 2022

Answer (score 9):

**Summary:  rename-and-move in VS2019 with git, retaining git history, leveraging R# a bit, automatic dependent project reference updating (important for sln's with many projects, we have >200)**

I have been using the following steps to rename-and-move C# projects in Visual Studio 2019.  This process uses R# to adjust namespaces.  The git history is retained by doing a "git mv" (avoiding add/delete history drop).

Two phases:  1) rename the project in place and 2) move the project.

(Uses tip from [base2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641493/base2) re unloading projects.)

**Rename**

1. VS | Solution Explorer | right-click project | Rename (e.g., Utils.Foo to Foo).
2. VS | Solution Explorer | right-click project | Properties | change assembly name, default namespace and Assembly Information fields
3. Do 1 and 2 for corresponding test project (e.g., Utils.Foo.Tests)
4. VS | Solution Explorer | right-click projects (production and test) | Refactor | Adjust Namespaces
5. XAML files that use the project may need to be updated (manually or with an appropriate global search and replace)
6. Rebuild All
7. Commit!! (to commit changes before moves)

Note:  The folder in Windows Explorer remains the old name to this point (e.g., Utils.Foo).  This is fixed in the move steps.

**Move**

This method: 1) retains git history, 2) leverages R# to adjust namespaces atomically and 3) updates dependent projects en masse (avoids tedious manual editing of dependent sln and csproj files).

1. unload all the projects in the solution (so that removal of the target project does not trigger changes in dependent projects)

   VS | select all solution folders under the Solution | right-click Unload Projects
2. move folders using git (so history is maintained)

a) open Developer Command Prompt for 2019

b) git status (to illustrate “nothing to commit, working tree clean”)

c) git mv the project
e.g., git mv "C:\Code\foo\foo\Utils.Foo" "C:\Code\Foo"

d) git status to view/verify change

3. remove the project

VS | Solution Explorer | select project | right-click | Remove
(since all projects are unloaded, this will correctly NOT remove the references to it in dependent projects)

4. re-add the project (to the new location in the tree in Solution Explorer)

a) VS | Solution Explorer | select target parent folder | right-click | Add | Existing Project

5. reload all projects

*IMPORTANT:*  Confirm that *.csproj files for dependent projects have been updated.

(VS | Team Explorer | Changes | double-click any dependent csproj listed | inspect-verify ProjectReference path change)

6. Manually fix paths in the single moved *.csproj file

Use Notepad++ (or other text editor) to fix the paths.  Often this can be done with a simple search-and-replace (e.g., ../../../../ to ../../).

This will update...

a) GlobalAssmeblyInfo.cs references

b) paths to packages

c) paths to Dependency Validation diagram files

d) paths to ruleset paths (e.g., `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\..\..\SolutionDependencyValidation\IgnoreWarnings.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`)

7. Close and re-Open the solution (to get the project references into good shape)

Save All, Close Solution, I prefer to delete bin and obj folders to be clean of history, Re-open Solution

8. Validate

a) VS | Team Explorer | Changes

i) should see Staged Changes that reveal the files that moved
ii) should see dependent projects (*.csproj) that were nicely updated
review the csproj diffs and notice that the paths have been beautifully updated!! (this is the magic that avoids laboriously manually updating the csproj files using a text editor)

b) in Windows Explorer, verify old location is empty

c) Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution, Run unit tests, Launch apps in sln.

9. Commit!!

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was to:

1. Remove the project from the solution.
2. Edit the project file with a text editor.
3. Update all relative paths to the "packages". In my case I had to change `..\packages` to `..\..\..\packages` since I moved the project to a deeper folder.
4. Load the project back into the solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I solved with move the references and in less than 15 minutes, without change the references.

For me the solution was simple:

1. Move your files where you need.
2. Delete the folder with name .vs. Must be as not visible folder.
3. Open the solution file (.sln) using a simple editor like note or
   notepad++.
4. Change the reference where your file is, using the following
   structure: if you put your project in the same folder remove the
   previous folder or the reference "..\"; if you put in a above folder
   add the reference "..\" or the name of the folder.
5. Save the file with the changes.
6. Open the project file (.csproj) and do the same, remove or add the
   reference.
7. Save the changes.
8. Open the solution file.

Examples:

In solution file (.sln)

- Original:
  *Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PATH1.UI",
  "**ScannerPDF**\PATH1.UI\PATH1.UI.csproj",
  "{A26438AD-E428-4AE4-8AB8-A5D6933E2D7B}"
  Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") =
  "PATH1.DataService",
  "**ScannerPDF**\PATH1.DataService\PATH1.DataService.csproj",
  "{ED5A561B-3674-4613-ADE5-B13661146E2E}"*

  New:
  *Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PATH1.MX.UI", "PATH1.MX.UI\PATH1.UI.csproj",
  "{A26438AD-E428-4AE4-8AB8-A5D6933E2D7B}"
  Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") =
  "PATH1.DataService",
  "PATH1.DataService\PATH1.DataService.csproj",
  "{ED5A561B-3674-4613-ADE5-B13661146E2E}"*

In project file:

- Original:

  New:

  Original reference:
  *....\lib\RCWF\2018.1.220.40\TelerikCommon.dll*

  New reference:
  *..\lib\RCWF\2018.1.220.40\TelerikCommon.dll*

Answer (score 4):

**Most easy way, which I found for myself**

I tried multiple times till I found a working way.. For example you want to **move your project** from **sln** folder to **mySource** folder.

1. **Remove your Project:** In the SolutionExplorer of Visual Studio select your Project you want to change the directory, *Press Delete* -> Project gets removed. It still remains in your **sln** folder.
2. **Copy it to your Path:** In the windows explorer *copy* your whole project to your **mySource** folder. -> Now you are ready to include it.
3. **Include back your Project:** In the SolutionExplorer of Visual Studio *add Existing Project* and select your project from **mySource** folder. -> Project is now back in your Solution.
4. **Adjust your Project References:** *Check every Reference in your Project.* On your Project -> Dependencies -> Project -> you see your project references. If there is a yellow Warning sign on a project reference than is it wrong. *Delete your project reference* and *add it new*. [image]
5. **Rebuild your Project:** and let it Run. Afterwards you can *delete* your project in the **sln** folder, which is not anymore in use.

**That works. Have fun :)**

Answer (score 1):

It's easy in VS2012; just use the change mapping feature:

1. Create the folder where you want the solution to be moved to.
2. Check-in all your project files (if you want to keep you changes), or rollback any checked out files.
3. Close the solution.
4. Open the Source Control Explorer.
5. Right-click the solution, and select "Advanced -> Remove Mapping..."
6. Change the "Local Folder" value to the one you created in step #1.
7. Select "Change".
8. Open the solution by double-clicking it in the source control explorer.

Comment: That is, iff you're using TFS?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Community 2019, I did what Victor David Francisco Enrique says, but needed only to delete the .vs invisible folder.

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer. What did he do? Even if you answer that you're only editing an answer, which you could have done as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the project folder to new destination
2. Remove your project from solution (Right-click the project in "Solution Explorer" and choose "Remove")
3. Then add existing project to solution (Right-click the project in "Solution Explorer" and choose "Add" then "Existing project")
4. Change path to "packages" folder in "YourProjectName.csproj" file (Open in notepad and change paths for linked packages)

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2015

1. Unload your project in the solution explorer
2. Create a new solution
3. Copy the projects to the new solution's folder
4. Right click the solution, add existing project.
5. If you use some framework such as `MVC`, you may need to add the reference in the reference manager.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this try this it worked for me.

In visual studio 2017 community edition it creates a project at this path
"C:\Users\mark\source\repos\mipmaps\mipmaps"
This will create a access to file is denied issue

Now, you can fix that this way.

close your visual studio process.
Then, find your project and copy the project folder
But, first make a Sub-folder Named Projects inside of your visual studio 2017 folder in documents.
Next, paste the project folder inside of your visual studio 2017 Project folder not the main visual studio 2017 folder it should go into the Sub-folder called Projects.
Next, restart Visual studio 2017
Then, choose Open project Solution
Then, find your project you pasted in your visual studio 2017 Projects folder
Then clean the Project and rebuild it , It, should build and compile just fine.
Hope, this Helped out anybody else.
Not to sure why Microsoft thought building your projects in a path where it needs write permissions is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the changes in Git to be shown as moves/renames instead of delete & adds.
So I did a combo of the above and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37079682/200824).

```
mkdir subdirectory
git mv -k ./* ./subdirectory
# check to make sure everything moved (see below)
git commit
```

And adjust the paths of the projects and of the assemblies from the nuget Pkg's in the sln file via a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me vb2019. I copied my source project folder. I then pasted the project, and renamed the the folder to whatever. In order to break the ties back to the source project folder, I temporarily renamed the source folder. I opened my destination project. The paths to the forms and modules were re-discovered in the local folder. I went through all my forms and modules to make sure they were working. I ran the project. I closed the project. I renamed the source project folder back to is't original name. I can open both projects at the same time without errors.

Answer (score 0):

- Close the solution and move your project to new folder/location
- Re-open your solution
- Project should be loaded with '+' sigh referring as non checked in part. All the files
  of the project will be shown as Renamed.
- If not working after reopening right click on the project and click unload and then
  reload.
- It worked in VS2019

Answer (score -1):

Group related projects together using solution folders

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6c756s6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Seems off-topic

Answer (score -2):

No sure why all answers have overlooked at the most simple solution. Just run the "Command Prompt app" (in the windows bar search for CMD and it will appear automatically)

then just type the following  command (change the path where relevant for your own case:)

```
robocopy /E C:\Users\Peter\source\repos D:\Peter\repos
```

What robocopy does is to "copies file data from one location to another." and the "secret source" is the / E that means  **"Copies subdirectories. This option automatically includes empty directories."**

Enjoy!!! :-)

[image: CMD Promt]

Comment: This is not a solution, as it's just an explanation on how to move files within Windows environment, not VS environment