# Move all files of a git directory into subdirectory and maintain history

Tags: git

How can I move all the files of my current directory into a new directory and retain the history.

I have tried:

```
git mv . old_app
```

But I get:

```
fatal: bad source, source=, destination=old_app/
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think, this is invalid operation you are doing.

You cannot move the current directory (pwd) `.` to the other directory which is inside of the current directory. Even `mv` command will not work. As the output says

```
mv: cannot move ‘.’ to ‘someDir/.’: Device or resource busy
```

Using * in git mv also says

```
git mv * someDir
fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=curDir, destination=curDir/someDir
```

Go up one directory level, and select the directories which is to be moved to the target directory. In this case also **you cannot make parent directory to move inside child directory.** Parent directory contents/files can be made to move to target directory but not the parent directory itself.

Comment: See my answer for how to do this using Extended Globbing without suppressing errors.

Comment: Yes the way you execute the command `git mv * someDir` is rejected. However, I managed to `git mv` each folder and file one by one, to another directory which is also under the project root :-)

Answer (score 63):

The solution to make the `git mv` work is simple:

`git mv -k * ./subDir`

The [option `-k`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) will simply skip all actions that would produce an error. This will probably not work in older versions of git.

Remember there is the `mv` and the `git move`.

The normal bash move usage is: `mv * ./subDir` which will only produce a warning but still move your files.

Whereas the `git mv` with the usage `git mv * ./subDir` will produce the fatal error and abort the move:

`fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=currentDir/subDir, destination=currentDir/subDir/subDir`

Comment: So you apply `-k` and you skip moving the files. How is that useful?

Comment: Because the mv command always fails because it tries to move the directory into itself. Because of this the operation would become an endless loop and therefore it produces an error and nothing is moved. But with the -k option it will not fail and also won't end in an endless loop.

Comment: Yes, but it will actually do nothing, I've tried it.

Comment: @LuxDie Sorry for the late response. I just tested the solution again and I can tell it works. You need to make sure your files are in a Git-repository and are committed. Are you sure you are getting the above `can not move ... into itself` error message without the `-k`?

Comment: This works for me. It's not just suppressing errors messages, it's suppressing *actions* that would be errors. `mkdir folder; giv mv -k * folder/`. This results in everything now being in the directory named `folder`. Using version 2.8.3 of git.

Comment: I will also add that you can also use the `-k` option with `git mv` to move hidden files. Because `.git` is controlled by Git, without the `-k` option git would return an error and refuse to move it. Running with the `-k` option it will skip the `.git` folder. ie. `git mv -k .* directory`

Comment: I believe what @LuxDie encountered was using older version of git. I test 1.9.1 and had same result as LuxDie

Comment: You may also experience difficulties using PowerShell; try git `mv -k (get-childItem *) folder/` instead. (See [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1050326/git-mv-returns-bad-source-in-powershell).)

Answer (score 16):

You need to enable [Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) so you can use regular expressions.

If you're using [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) shell type this [`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) (shell option) command prior to executing the command featuring the glob:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

(you can also add this to your `~/.bash_profile` if you don't want type this every time)

Then you can use the following syntax:

```
$ git mv ./!(exclude_me|exclude_me) ./destination_folder
```

For example if this is your folder structure:

```
root
├── aardvark
├── contrib
|   ├── folder1
|   └── folder2
├── custom
|   ├── folder1
|   └── folder2
├── elephant
├── hippopotamus
└── zebra
```

And you run the following in the `root` directory:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ git mv ./!(custom|contrib) ./contrib
```

You'll end up with this:

```
root
├── contrib
|   ├── aardvark
|   ├── elephant
|   ├── folder1
|   ├── folder2
|   ├── hippopotamus
|   └── zebra
└── custom
    ├── folder1
    └── folder2
```

Add the `-n` flag if you want to do a test run and make sure the command will execute without errors:

```
$ git mv -n ./!(exclude_me|exclude_me) ./destination_folder
```

Add the `-k` flag to include files not under version control:

```
$ git mv -k ./!(exclude_me|exclude_me) ./destination_folder
```

---

If using [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/) shell, enable extended globbing in the following way and use `^` to negate the pattern.

```
$ setopt extendedglob
$ git mv ^(exclude_me|exclude_me) ./destination_folder
$ git mv ^exclude_me ./destination_folder
```

Comment: This answer helped me to move an angular project to a dir called `client`, had to exclude `.git` and `..` also: `git mv ./!(client|.editorconfig|..|.|.git) ./client`

Answer (score 6):

So, I got into the same problem and what did the job for me was

```
for file in $(ls | grep -v 'yourfolder'); do git mv $file yourfolder; done;
```

Comment: How is this not the answer??

Comment: Works great! But I think you can leave out the grep, can't you? `for file in $(ls); do git mv $file yourfolder; done;` I tried out on Windows Git Bash

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you can use:

```
FOR %F IN (*) DO IF NOT %F == old_app git mv %F old_app
FOR /D %D IN (*) DO IF NOT %D == old_app git mv %D old_app
```

If you're doing this in a batch file, you'll need to use `%%F` and `%%D` instead of `%F` and `%D`, respectively.

Answer inspired by https://superuser.com/a/112141 .

Comment: On Windows Powershell, you can use this:`dir –exclude old_app | %{git mv $_.Name old_app}`, inspired by https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

Comment: @ScottStafford How can I use your command in a batch file that I call from powershell? I get the following error `'{git' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: You should perhaps add quotes around `%F` in case it contains spaces, and perhaps check for ".git" folder too in case you are in repository's root

Answer (score 4):

```
git mv $(git ls-tree --name-only HEAD) <new-directory>
```

will do what you require. I believe this is the cleanest way.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree

Comment: "git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD path" works great but don't keep the structure of the files moving to the new directory :/

Comment: It does. It lists directories which you then move.

Comment: Thanks mate, at the end I use this other approach instead:
git mv path/origin path/new-name && git mv path/new-name other-directory

Answer (score 1):

I want to move all png files to images subdirectory in the local and remote repo:

```
mkdir images
git add *.png
git mv  *.png ./images
git commit -m "move"
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are a windows user, [this](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rename.html) is one solution for you.

1. Install Turtoise Git if you have not done that
2. Select the folder you want to move
3. Right mouse button, Turtoise git, Rename

[image]