# How to move git repository folder into new folder like,- src/* to src/main/* for converting Eclipse based Java Application to Maven Project

Tags: java, git, maven

I am in the process making my Java application Maven-based.

So I have to move my `src/*` into `src/main/*`.

Please help me out with the `git` commands.

Comment: You mean `git mv`? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: I've tried executing `git mv src/ src/main/`. But I have got a error like,- `fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=src, destination=src/main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to move the content of `src/` rather than src/ itself

```bash
cd src
mkdir main
git mv -k * ./main/
```

On the [`git mv -k` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv#Documentation/git-mv.txt--k), see "[Move all files of a git directory into subdirectory and maintain history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35201800/6309)"

Comment: After this I did `git add *`, `git commit -m "my comment"`, `git pull` and `git push`. So it had been checked-in successfully!

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam Well done! Don't forget that git add is used with a dot, not '`*`'. See "**[Difference between `.` (dot) and `*` (asterisk) wildcards in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509019/6309)**".