# GIT - how to properly 'git init' a git repository's 'upper' directory

Tags: git

I have a directory `./a/b/`. Only `b` is a git repo. Now I've decided that the git repo tree should start from `a`, and include (if possible) all information about `b` repo.

I've tried to just `git init` from `a`, and commit. But when `a` is cloned, it has an empty `b`. (which is interesting, because as far as I know git usually ignores empty directories)

It it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cut and paste your `.git` folder to `a` and add everything.

```
mv .git ../.git  #move the repo  
cd .. #go to the parent dir
git add --all  #add everything
git commit -m 'moves everything into a subfolder'  #commit everything
```

git will recognise everything as "renamed": (example with one file)

> git status
>   On branch master
>   Changes to be comitted:
>      (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> renamed: test -> b/test

Answer (score 0):

I propose to stay in your repo in `./a/b` and move all tracked files to a subdirectory `./a/b/a/b` via `git mv filename`. After this your repo has the correct structure which is everything which really counts. You can then move the whole repo to `.` to get exactly what you want. `git mv` supports the usage of wildcards to make this easier.

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667308/git-move-file-and-directory-into-a-sub-directory-along-with-commit-history). You can get a bit more automation via this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918589/464136).