# Moving a file to different folder along with history in git

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

First of all, I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18667308/2894411) which is exactly the same what I am addressing here. But the problem is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21558567/2894411) given in the question, does not work for me.

The solution given is this:

> `git filter-branch --tree-filter "cd x; mkdir -p p/q; mv [files & sub-dirs] p/q" HEAD`

to move files & subdirs under `x` to `x/p/q`.

This is exactly what I want. But this does not work when I tried.

My directory structure is:

> ```
> mdwtest
>
>    |-src
>    |   |-main
>    |   |    |-java
>    |   |    |    |-a.txt
>    |   |-test
>    |   |    |-java
> ```

I tried this command from `cmd.exe` in `mdwtest` directory which is my git local repository. I ran `cmd.exe` as administrator.

> ```
> git filter-branch --tree-filter "cd D:/gittraining/mdwtest/src; mv main/java/ /test/java/" HEAD
> ```

But it gave the below output in `cmd.exe` console:

```
D:\gittraining\mdwtest>git filter-branch --tree-filter "cd

D:/gittraining/mdwtest/src; mv main/java/  /test/java/" HEAD Rewrite
09a1198eeb1bf26a1245ea00cae38f22e91fd708 (1/15)mv: cannot move
`main/java/' to `/test/java' tree filter failed: cd

D:/gittraining/mdwtest/src; mv main/java/ /test/java/ rm: cannot
remove `/d/gittraining/mdwtest/.git-rewrite/revs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `/d/gittraining/mdwtest/.git-rewrite':
Directory not empty
```

What I can get out of this is that it has some problem over moving `main/java` to `test/java` and I don't have any clue on what could have prevented it from doing so.

Actually I expected `src/main/java/a.txt` file to have moved to `src/test/java` along with history.

While the solution seems to have worked for many people, looks like something is going wrong in my case.

Could you help explaining me on what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv main/java/ /test/java/` seems strange. It should be

```
mv main/java/ test/java/
```

(`test`, not `/test`)

Other than that, make sure `a.txt` is not opened in some editor or Windows Explorer.