# Bitbucket - moving files within repository and preserving istory

Tags: bitbucket

I need to create a new folder within bitbucket repo and move existing files there while preserving their history.

Would anybody recommend me best way how to do that?

I found some similiar question here, but they are either old or specified for github and I am not sure if it applies for bitbucket as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving a file to different folder along with history in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647772/moving-a-file-to-different-folder-along-with-history-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got rights to test it.

I found out it's enough to move files, their history remains (it's true for Bitbucket as well).

Just if anybody runs into the same problem, this might be helpful.