# Moving file(s) and it's history to new branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, branching-and-merging

I made many different changes in a single branch and now I want to move some of the changes to a new branch so that my pull-requests are more specific.

Now I know that I can do something like: `git checkout <branchname> -- filename`
but the catch is that I want to retain the files history.

Currently with my limited git knowledge I can only think of 2 ways to do this:

1. Create a new branch and cherrypick all the commits that contain the files I need and then re-commit them to my new branch one by one.
2. Create a new branch from the current branch and then do a revert-commit on all the commits that I don't want.

I have over 50 commits since the last pull request and cherry-picking / reverting commits one by one is a tedious process.

Is there a simple way to move files to a new branch while retaining it's history?

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

create patches at one shot,

```
git format-patch <sha_id_from>...<sha_id_to> <path1> <path2>
```

In your new branch to apply patches,

```
find . -name "00*" | sort | xargs git am
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special for you to do, because in Git, files don't *have* history.  (That is, you just rename the file, using, e.g., `git mv` or `mv` followed by `git add -u`, and commit.)

Instead, Git's commits *are* the history.  If you want to read history, you read commits.

#### Git offers `git log --follow`

Git will, when you ask it, *synthesize* a file history by reading commit history and looking, in each commit, at that file.  If the file, compared to the version of that same file in the parent commit, is *the same*, Git simply doesn't *display* the commit.  The result seems to be the file's history, but it's not: it's just "the commits in which the file differs from version stored in the commit's parent commit."<sup>1</sup>

This is where the mismatch occurs: if "that one particular file" means `path/to/file.ext` and at some point the notionally-identical file has a *different name*, `p2/othername.otherext` for instance, well, now Git's synthetic-file-history-maker is looking under the wrong name.

What Git offers to combat this is `git log --follow`.  The actual implementation of `--follow` is a crude hack: Git still just looks for one name at a time.  What `--follow` does is make Git notice that, in some commit, the comparison of "previous commit" against "this commit" results in a diff that says "rename `p2/othername.otherext` to `path/to/file.ext`".  So, from that point onward-into-the-past, Git stops looking for `path/to/file.ext` and starts looking instead for `p2/othername.otherext`.

#### ... which doesn't always work

This crude hack works well enough for most cases, but cannot track two different names across commit-chains that fork-and-re-merge:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         *--o--...
         \       /
          o--o--o
```

When Git, working right to left (newer commits to older ones), encounters the merge commit `*`, it would have to follow *two* parents back in time, along the top line and along the bottom line.  It actually does this one commit at a time, or, in some very common cases—using what Git calls *history simplification*—just drops one of these branches entirely, following *only* the top or bottom line of commits.

History simplification is enabled by default when looking at specific path names.  Since `git log --follow` looks at *one* path name, Git is looking at specific path names and hence has history simplification turned on.  This helps it out when it's doing the `--follow` code, since it can't remember both names (it's just not that smart).  Should you turn off history simplification, which you can with various `git log` options, the `--follow` code simply breaks down: it changes the single to-be-followed name and you don't see an appropriate synthetic history anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup>This notion gets trickier at merge commits.  If `path/to/file.ext` is the same as the same file in *one* of the parent commits, but different from the same file in the *other* parent commit, is it changed?  This is also where history simplification comes in.  A *combined diff* lists only files where the file differs from the version in all parents, and the history simplifier normally follows only the commit(s) that *do* change the file.

There's a related tricky bit if you look at `git log -p` output (with or without `--follow`), which is that `git log` doesn't *print* the combined diffs by default.  You must add `-c` or `--cc`, or use `-m` to split merges, to see diffs here.

Answer (score 1):

The work flow should be similar as you listed. But there have some commands can make the work flow efficient:

1. **Get the list of the commits which changed specify files**

   Assume you want to get the commits which changed `*.cs`, `*.txt` and `test.sh`, then you can get the commits which changed any of the files by

   ```
   git log --grep=*.cs --format="%h  %cd" && git log --grep=*.txt --format="%h  %cd" && git log --grep=test.sh --format="%h  %cd"
   ```
2. **Create a new branch**

   You can create the branch from the initial commit so that the commit history on the new branch will record the visions that the specified files changed as the step list:

   ```
   git checkout -b newbranch <commit id for the initial commit>
   ```
3. **Cherry-pick the commits listed in step1 from old to new**

   Cherry-pick the commits in step1 from old to new based on the commit date. You can also cherry-pick the list of commits by script.
4. **Revert or remove the list of commits in `master` branch**

   You can use `git revert <commit>` to revert the commits listed in step1 one by one. But it will increase the commit history on master branch.

   The other way remove the commits in master branch by interactive rebase. In master branch, you can use `git rebase -i master~49` (assume you have 50 commits on `master` branch).

   Then in the interactive window, change `pick` to `drop` before the commits which your want to remove. The the interactive window should look like:

   ```
   pick <second commit>
   pick <third commit>
   ...
   drop <m-th commit>
   ...
   drop <n-th commit>
   ...
   pick <50th commit>
   ```

Answer (score -2):

you have to merge one branch into another

the command is--git merge [the branch name which u want to merge]

Comment: Merging is not the solution to OP's problem