# Moved project, now references are broken

Tags: visual-studio

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622537/4298546) instructions to move a project to another folder, now all of my references are broken and I don't know how to fix them.

[image: Broken References]

Answer (score 7):

open .csproj and remove this tag

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"> bla-bla </Target>
```

Comment: Still worked in Dec 2021 on VS 2019.