# Safe move .net project to subfolder with reference update

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Here the story, at first I created new empty solution with name TestSolution. Next I added new project with name TestProject and add EntityFramework 6.1.3 reference via NuGet Package Manager. After that NuGet Package Manager create folder packages and add Reference

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

After a while I decided to create subfolder with name Subfolder and move TestProject there.

I excepted what new Reference will looks like

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

How can I move project and update references without manual update project files?

Comment: You don't. You'll need to manually fix these issues.

Comment: Can you argue why? I can update reference with Update-Package -reinstall command but can I move project I elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is

- Move visual studio project in one command is not possible and you should using one of the following solutions in [Visual Studio move project to a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620027/visual-studio-move-project-to-a-different-folder) Unforunately you should do all the work manually
- Call Update-Package -reinstall in Nuget Package Manager console