# VSCode Dotnet Core Move Project To New Folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, csproj

I had a single csproj in my project in Visual Studio Code and wanted to rehouse it into a sub folder so that I could also have a test.csproj alongside so I created two new folders at the root:

root
--api
--test

And I used VSCode to move all the existing files into the new api folder so that I could have two csproj files separated out into two folders.

Everything went FUBAR, the only way I could fix it was to create a new project and copy all the files I needed across.

Is there currently a better way to do this without messing up all references to the existing csproj?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio move project to a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620027/visual-studio-move-project-to-a-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

below is how we can create a solution and a console project in the same directory to simulate your situation

```
mkdir test
cd test 
dotnet new sln 
dotnet new console
dotnet sln add test.csproj
```

now you have a solution in test folder which it has a console type project named test.csproj

to relocate the console project to a sub directory :

```
dotnet sln remove test.csproj
mkdir console 
mv obj Program.cs test.csproj console/.
cd console
```

refactor all the references,namespaces and file names

```
rm -R obj
cd ..
dotnet sln add console/console.csproj
```

test:

```
dotnet run --project console/console.csproj
```

Hello World!

this is a practical way to relocate a project in dotnet core.
P.S. the command are valid for Linux

Comment: I don't know if this is valid for Visual Studio Code, I thought VSCode projects were folder oriented rather than solution (sln) oriented?

Comment: In vsCode you can use the bash terminal for it