# Moving a Visual Studio solution and projects, then establishing it with a different remote

Tags: git, azure-devops

I need to start a Visual Studio project over but establish it with a different remote. I looked this up here on Stack Overflow and came across this post "[Visual Studio move project to a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620027/visual-studio-move-project-to-a-different-folder)". That almost helps, but I need a little more help.

The project is in Git with the remote in Azure DevOps Services. I need to start it over but not have it tied to the same Git remote repo in Azure DevOps. Instead, I've got to establish a new remote in Azure DevOps for the project, from the new location on my local machine. I am assuming that I can use the answers to the post I've linked to.

Do I also not copy the .git folder from the old location, then from the new location perform a `git init` to establish a new local git repo and establish a different git upstream in Azure DevOps? (At this point I am not concerned with keeping the history of changes to the project in the old location. This is a fresh start.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I also not copy the `.git` folder from the old location, then from the new location perform a `git init` to establish a new local git repo and establish a different git upstream in Azure DevOps?

**Yes**... **if** what you are saying that you don't need to keep your old history is true.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm saying. In this case there's not much history anyway, so we don't lose anything by not keeping it.