# How do I make Azure Pipelines aware of the YAML file already in the repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Recently I asked about [Moving a Visual Studio solution and projects, then establishing it with a different remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178637/moving-a-visual-studio-solution-and-projects-then-establishing-it-with-a-differ). Using the answer, I got I've copied my project into a new local repo and established the remote in Azure DevOps Services. However, now I'm trying to get the Azure build pipeline to work, but Azure Pipeline doesn't recognize azure-pipelines.yml file in the repo. I tried importing the pipeline, but that action wants a build pipeline JSON file, which the YAML file isn't.

How do I get Azure Pipelines to recognize the YAML file as build pipeline file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new pipeline and select: `Existing Azure PipelineS YAML file` and then pick your yaml file.

[image]

Comment: Is this still valid? I don't see this option when selecting 'Azure Repos Git' on the 'Wheres your code' screen

Comment: Yes. I checked and I have it available.

Answer (score 0):

I think the repository should be an Azure Git Repo to show the existing Azure pipeline file. Correct me if I am wrong, but my repo is a Gerrit and I can't see the option to select an Existing Pipeline file.

Comment: I think you're right, but I haven't tried it myself. 5 years ago I was using TFVC as well as Git, in Azure DevOps. But about that time I stopped using TFVC and migrated those repos to Git. I bring this up to say I don't even know if TFVC repos in ADO are aware of Azure Pipeline YAML files, because I've never tried that combination and I wasn't interested to try.