# Is it possible to rename a project in Visual Studio such that its folder name is also renamed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Let's assume we're working on a project called MyProject.
I'd like to be able to change its name to MyProject2 AND have its folder name also renamed to MyProject2.

Is this possible from Visual Studio? If not, how to make this happen "outside" it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename your project to your new name. It will change the .csproj file automatically which in 2010 is the name of the project. Close Visual Studio. Rename the directory.

Open your solution file to change directory now. Your solution file will point to the new project but will reference the wrong directory.

Before:

```
 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename",    "Stackoverflow_4560662\Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename.csproj", "{7CCD10BF-48BA-44E2-B071-D4ED8067ACA1}"
```

After

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename", "Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename\Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename.csproj", "{7CCD10BF-48BA-44E2-B071-D4ED8067ACA1}"
```

Notice the two parts
"Stackoverflow_4560662\Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename.csproj" becomes
"Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename\Stackoverflow_4560662_Rename.csproj"

This is the only way I've been able to rename a directory for a project. I hope someone finds a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

Following may be one solution

- Close the solution.
- Rename the folders outside Visual Studio.
- Open the solution, ignoring the warnings.
- Go through all unavailable projects.

  - Set the property 'File Path' to the new location.
  - Reload the project.
  - In case you didn't rename the project, rename it (F2).

Check answer

[How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty much a novice at this stuff but I had the same issue, my resolution was to just copy and paste my code into a new project and save it using the new name I needed.  Probably not the best method but it's simple and it works.

Comment: you'll lose the file history doing it this way :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anybody but all I did was rename the solution and associated folders etc.
Unfortunately when you open it says it can't find your project(s).
To get around this I opened the solution itself in a text editor (notepad++) and renamed where it finds the Project . . . and it works.

Andy

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're talking about a single VB.NET project in a solution.

AFAIK, You're not supposed to rename the 'My Project' folder, that's the VS default name for all VB.NET project.

Just select the project/solution in VS Solution Explorer and Click F2 to simply rename it.