# How can I change the name of my project and have it reflect everywhere?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, rename

I created a project in Visual Studio 2010 but I mispelled the name well into development.

If I right click, and rename the project, it seems the changes aren't cascaded to folders and classes.

For example, if my project was named Foa and I added a class, the namespace would be:

```
namespace Foa
{
    public class Bar
```

If I renamed the project to Foo, the class stays:

```
namespace Foa
{
    public class bar
```

Is there a way to cascade that change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to rename a project in Visual Studio such that its folder name is also renamed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560662/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-project-in-visual-studio-such-that-its-folder-name-is)

Comment: More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio (almost a duplicate question but not quite)

Comment: Is the difference in case on "bar" intentional? Looks like a mistake to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the namespace in one spot and then Ctrl+. on it and choose the refactor option. This will change the namespace throughout.

Comment: Ok, this impressed me. It actually works! I wonder why it's so hidden though. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say it's hidden. You can also right-click on a "thing" (class, namespace, parameter, etc.) and choose the Refactor\Rename option. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default namespace in the project properties, then use a refactor tool to change the namespaces. Resharper has a fix inconsistent namespaces tool that will do it but you can just use the visual studio refactor to do it manually.