# Rename the project folder without changing the project name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

## Context

My solution "dashboard" contains only one project also called "Dashboard".

I want to rename the project folder in "Files" without changing the project name.

## Before

[image]

## After

[image]

## Issue

When i open the solution in VS, i get this error:

[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4560726/652669) but I haven't the property "File Path".

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the project which is unavailable, and press F4. You can then change the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the project from the solution and then re-add it with "Add existing project" option.