# Renaming project directory in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What would be a sequence of operations to rename an MVC3 project directory in Visual Studio 2010? I can rename a project without any problems. However, if I try to detach it from solution and rename the directory containing it, attaching it back fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method to preserve references:

- Rename project in Visual Studio (references should be updated to new
  name)
- Close Visual Studio
- Rename Directory
- Edit Solution.sln in text editor--change directory referencing renamed project
- Reopen solution and build

Assumtions:

- project named DataAccess is renamed to DataAccess2
- project directories located at src\ relative to the solution directory

Original:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DataAccess", "src\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj", "{030E25DF-77F2-012E-94EC-4E4D7D1C62E8}"
```

After renaming project, before editing .sln:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DataAccess2", "src\DataAccess\DataAccess2.csproj", "{030E25DF-77F2-012E-94EC-4E4D7D1C62E8}"
```

After editing .sln:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DataAccess2", "src\DataAccess2\DataAccess2.csproj", "{030E25DF-77F2-012E-94EC-4E4D7D1C62E8}"
```

Comment: disclaimer: I do have Resharper and it is possible the reference updating that occurs with the rename is handled by resharper and not VS.

Comment: Nice works well.  I don't have Resharper and the project reference was updated by VS.

Comment: Just realized this does not update the namespace(s), assembly name, or Assembly info in the Project properties tab. If this is desired it should be part of step 1

Comment: Doesn't work for me. VS still stores absolute paths somewhere. When I open the solution after all these steps it complaints that it cannot load the project that I moved. I have to clarify: it's an MVC3 project.

Comment: @Reality Analyst, in your MVC3 solution, which project did you move?
Did you save the .sln before reopening the VS?
The solution I modified was also an MVC3 project.

Comment: also to note, the renaming the project (inside VS, 1st 2 bullets) and the moving of the project directory (VS closed, 3rd and 4th bullets) are separate tasks, you can do either one independently, or in reverse order.

Comment: I'm trying to move the main MVC project. I've just tried your procedure on a new solution and it worked. I have no idea why it doesn't work on my original application. Maybe it's because I've added entity schema to it, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

- Rename the project in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio
- Remove the project from the Solution in Visual Studio
- Rename the project folder on the file system
- Add the project back to the Solution in Visual Studio

Downside is you will lose any project references and you will have to redo them.