# How to rename solution, solution folder, project folder, package/filter folder and vcxproj file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've having problems doing any of these above with my game project. There are plenty of answer online already and I looked through all of them but they didn't work for me or having different scenario. Here is my situation:

[image: This is my Solution]

This is what my solution looks like. I changed the project name from **`X-Power`** to **`Neo_Elements`** within the visual studio, which works. But it doesn't affect the actual physical folder.

The physical file path and name for the .vcxproj file is `...\Neo_Elements\WorldScrollingGame\WorldScrollingGame.vcxproj`.

The physical file path and name for the .sln file is 
`...\Neo_Elements\X-Power.sln`

What I want to do:

1. Rename the solution to **`Neo_Elements`** (hence the `.sln` file will change accordingly)
2. Change the file path to `...\Neo_Elements\Neo_Elements\...`
3. Rename the .vcxproj file to `Neo_Elements.vcxproj`

So after the change the .sln file path and name should be
`...\Neo_Elements\Neo_Elements.sln`

the .vcxproj file path and name should be `...\Neo_Elements\Neo_Elements\Neo_Elements.vcxproj`

The solution and project name will both be **`Neo_Elements`**

What I did:

1. Rename the solution within Visual studio by F2 on the solution name.

What Happened:

The project no longer builds and creates bunch of compile error like this:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'resource.h': No such file or directory
```

I didn't even change the physical folder and I had no idea why the file cannot be found, and the location of the file missing seemed totally random to me. (not only those under `\WorldScrollingGame` but also some at deeper levels. Also lots of files were affected but only few files cannot be found).
When I tried to change the solution name back to **`X-Power`** it turns out that I cannot. It says
"The solution cannot be renamed because solution files with the specified name already exist", despite the fact that there is no `X-Power.sln` anymore. Nevertheless I've been completely stuck here and had to restore the entire solution from a backup (or change the name of .sln file manually in windows explorer). First attempt failed.

Then I started trying the second by change project folder outside VS.

What I did:

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio): closed VS, renamed the project director outside VS, edited .sln in text editor changing `"X-Power", "WorldScrollingGame\WorldScrollingGame.vcxproj"` to `"X-Power", "Neo_Elements\WorldScrollingGame.vcxproj"` (strangely the **`X-Power`** should be **`Neo_Elements`** since I edited the project name within VS, but somehow it didn't reflect the change here, unless this isn't a reflection of project name which by no means should be the case according to that link. But I didn't want to mess with the  solution name now because of what happened before).

What Happened:

It turns out I still receive bunch of compilation error similar to the one I got for my first attempt, no idea how to solve those.

So I didn't bother try the 3rd one since I don't even know how to

Please help! Really can't get around with these few.

Edit:
I know it might be better just to start of a new one and migrate all the files, but I've been unable to do the renaming in any situation before -- even a single solution renaming or a single project directory renaming. So I want to take this chance and figure out how this actually work, as it seemed to have worked for a lot of people

Comment: I've only ever had bad experiences trying to rename solutions like this - there may well BE a way, but it's extremely unintuitive if so, and you might have confused things sufficiently with your manual edits that it won't work anwyay. In your shoes I would nuke it from orbit and make a new solution from scratch. [Edit: you can keep the code files of course, and re-add them to the new solution once you've created it in the right place]

Answer (score 20):

The reason you are getting the message

*"The solution cannot be renamed because solution files with the specified name already exist"*

is probably because there is a '.sln' file with the same name in the root folder, or there are files related to that old solution still left in the project folders.

In the solution root folder find the '.vs' folder. Look for a folder with the same name that you are trying to name your solution to. Delete that folder.

Answer (score 7):

Here’s what I’ve done in the past.  First trying to rename a solution within VS doesn’t well.
Let’s assume you want to change your project name and solution name.

1. Close VS.
2. Make a back-up copy of your project before proceeding.
3. In Windows Explorer, navigate to your solution root.  This were you’ll find your  ProjectFile, packages and the .sln file.
4. Let’s change the project name by opening the Project File Folder and renaming the .csproj file.
5. Next right click your .sln file and select EDIT in note pad.  Look for a line like this: Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-xxxxxxxxx}")
   = "MyProject", "MyProject\MyProject.csproj", "{C1AD3829-E4BA-4BF1-85EB-672A85A4D35D}"  Change the .csproj name to
   your new name in step 4.  You may want to make the folder names are
   correct as well.
6. Save and close note pad.
7. Finally right click on the .sln file and select RENAME.  Choose your name and close.
8. Now open VS, select File>Open> Project Solution and navigate to the .sln file you just changed.
9. Hopefully that did the trick.  If not please carefully review your changes.

Comment: Renaming sln file manually stopped my solution from building: for some reason it started missing .h files in another folder, outside of the solution folder. No, my paths are not hardcoded. Everything is set with $(SolutionDir), $(ProjectDir), and all others, no hardcoded folders. The only thing I change is the solution file: MyProgram.sln to MyProgram2.sln and it stops building: starts missing headers and says I need C++ 17 support in my project(which is set in the project). As soon as I name my .sln file back to MyProgram.sln, it builds. I renamed my .sln file following @David Sapko's answer

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a suggestion which I think might work. Inside Visual Studio 2012 in solution explorer, find the file .vcxproj by opening all the nodes and seeing where it is. Then rename the file from there. Do the same for all other files of yours. After doing all this, your last task should be to change the solution name from inside the VS2012.
Hope this will help.
Any comments or response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a random folder with the exact name I was trying to assign to my solution, which was the problem. the folder appeared to be containing some VS-related unimportant data so I deleted it and I was able to rename my solution to what I wanted (be sure to backup your entire project before attempting this, just in case).