# Change file full path in a C# project in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In your opinion , it would be possible to change a file full path in a C# project, In Visual Studio 2012?? I ask this because in visualization, the properties box for a project file that contains full path appears as disable ( gray).
I would use the same file in different project, under the same solution, without duplicate file code .cs.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: Just move the project with all its files from Windows Explorer, file paths (unless linked) are always relative to the project file itself (and the project doesn't contain any absolute path).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @TheSolution's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901993/1037948):

1. File > New Project (or *Solution > Right-click > Add New Project*) > Class Library -- name it something like *"MyProject.Common"*
2. Add Existing Files (<kbd>Shift+Alt+A</kbd>) to project > choose files to share.  Or copy/paste
3. Delete old files in original project, as they've been copied to the shared project
4. Then in the projects in which you want to use the common files, *Project > Add Reference* > Choose from under "Solution > Projects" in left panel, check the "Common" project and choose "OK"
5. Include the namespace in the `using` section at the top of the code files which use the common code.

---

If you're talking about renaming a C# project *and its folder*, you have to do this manually in the `.sln` and `.csproj` files after renaming the project in the solution.  ex) If you want to rename "ME.MyProject" to "ME.YourProject":

1. Project > Properties (<kbd>ALT+ENTER</kbd> on project in Solution Explorer)
2. Change both "Assembly name" and "Default namespace"
3. Close VS (or unload solution)
4. Rename folder
5. Open `.sln` file in a text-editor and follow the manual steps below
6. Open the `.csproj` files of all other projects referencing this one and change references from "MyProject" to "YourProject".  Alternatively, delete and re-add project references within VS.

**`.sln`:**

*BEFORE:*

Note that the project file has been renamed, but not the path.

```
Project("{SOMEGUID}") = "ME.YourProject", "ME.MyProject\ME.YourProject.csproj", "{ANOTHERGUID}"
EndProject
```

*AFTER:*

```
Project("{SOMEGUID}") = "ME.YourProject", "ME.YourProject\ME.YourProject.csproj", "{ANOTHERGUID}"
EndProject
```

**`.csproj`:**

*BEFORE:*

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ME.MyProject\ME.YourProject.csproj">
  <Project>{ANOTHERGUID}</Project>
  <Name>ME.YourProject</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

*AFTER:*

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ME.YourProject\ME.YourProject.csproj">
  <Project>{ANOTHERGUID}</Project>
  <Name>ME.YourProject</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio for more information on the second interpretation

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to share a code file then you could add it as a Linked File. You can do this by right clicking on the project, selecting add existing item, finding the item in the open file dialog, and then before selecting it drop down the Open button and select the option for linked.

This will now link that code file to this project - or in other words - when it's changed in one place it's changed in both.

However, linked files are a very **hacky** way of providing shared functionality. The more appropriate approach is to build a Class Library with the functionality and add the DLL as a reference to the project. This means that you'll need to have a way of keeping that DLL up to date - but it's still generally more appropriate.