# rename a windows form app and its file C#

Tags: c#

I have created a windows form application in C# with name test_1. I want  to rename it. I manage to rename the solution but I can't rename the folder which contains the form, bin, resources etc. etc.

Any Help???

Comment: I believe this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio) solves your question. 

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in the Windows Explorer and then manually update the solution file (*.sln) to make sure that it still works. In addition you might want to update the assembly name and the default namespace in the project settings.