# Renaming generated DLL files in VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with 5 projects contained within that I have adapted for a new purpose. I have renamed all the project directories and changed all of the filenames within VS2013 as well. My problem is that all of the files generated upon a build still have the old name. Can anyone shed some light on how I might be able to get all the generated files to have a name that I specify when I hit build?

Thanks

Comment: Project properties -> Application -> Assembly name - type here what you want

Comment: That did the job nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is the same for all (decently recent) versions of Visual Studio.

- Right click on project in Solution Explorer
- Click on Properties
- Open "Application" left tab
- Change the fields Assembly Name and Default Namespace

You would also be interested by this answer and the other answer linked inside : https://stackoverflow.com/a/224788/461444 and you may also want to edit the "AssemblyInfo.cs" file in Properties subfolder of your project.

Also, if project have already been deployed somewhere, I suggest you to remove the old, badly named, assemblies because they can really mess the things on multiple DLL projects.

Answer (score 1):

Go on Properties of your relevant project and change Assembly name.