# VS2015: Safely changing a ASP.Net solution and project name

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

If I have a ASP.Net solution named "MyApp", that includes a single project "MyApp", and I then want to change both of them to "MyNewApp" - How can I do it safely, namely:

1. Without (breaking and then) needing to edit manually configuration files (that's what happened when I changed the names manually, and managed to fix it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39431022/6474510)).
2. Without (breaking and then) needing to edit the `.sln` file.
3. Without needing to change the projects path.

I mean, is/are there any menu/s in VS enabling that?

Comment: The short is answer is: No... This is a long standing issue, and still not possible in any version of VS. Apparently no one in Redmond ever needs this. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/211241/1220550

Comment: This [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a76bd66e-d021-45fe-952a-c393e81912ca) looks relevant, but might be out of date now

Answer (score 0):

There is no **SAFE** way of doing it.

> The best one is to use the find and replace for all the project files
>   with **Entire Solution** filter.

- First do copy the exact files in another location
- Open the solution in new location, Find existing name and replace with the new one.
- Open the .sln file with notepad and edit the file.