# how to rename nopcommerce plugin name in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

I customized `nopcommerce` Shipping By Weight plugin and i want to rename this plugin to for example `Nop.Plugin.MyPlugin`.can any body help me to do that?
i try below link but it does not worked.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)

Comment: Change it manually at all the places, what's bothering you?

Comment: @Div I had a problem that it calculate well but did not show shipping method on shipping page.i figure that by active payment method and problem solved.

Comment: That is different..from your question!

Comment: @div yes,i know,actually i said you what i did