# Xamarin assembly conflicts with the imported type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So I was changing my Project name and also my folders etc. I followed guide from here [How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio). All seemed to work, I can launch my app, but I got some erros and lots of lots of warnings

Warning example:

```
Warning CS0436  The type 'ObservableObject' in 'C:\Users\Godhaze\Documents\Volaapp\Volaapp\Volaapp\Base\ObservableObject.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'ObservableObject' in 'TodoScheduler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'C:\Users\Godhaze\Documents\Volaapp\Volaapp\Volaapp\Base\ObservableObject.cs'.    Volaapp C:\Users\Godhaze\Documents\Volaapp\Volaapp\Volaapp\Base\SelectableObject.cs 5   IntelliSense    Active
```

And errors like this:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'XamlFilePathAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    Volaapp C:\Users\Godhaze\Documents\Volaapp\Volaapp\Volaapp\obj\Debug\TodoScheduler.Pages.MenuPage.xaml.g.cs 14  IntelliSense    Active
```

The code of the error:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace TodoScheduler.Pages {


    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("C:\\Users\\Godhaze\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Volaapp\\Volaapp\\Volaapp\\Pa" +
        "ges\\MenuPage.xaml")]
    public partial class MenuPage : global::TodoScheduler.Controls.BasePage {

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView listView;

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MenuPage));
            listView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView>(this, "listView");
        }
    }
}
```

So I think Its an problem with Assembly?
I Added Reference In the first place, so what could be the problem?

Also do I need to change my namespaces? My projects name of PCL is "Volaapp" But Im using namespaces like: TodoScheduler.Base, because I think its refers to the Assembly. I might misunderstood this!

I tried cleaning the solution then deleting bin,obj folders and then rebuilding it, but that dident help.

So what should I do? I really want to fix this case and I can even give the full code of this to fix :(

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear, you have a type `ObservableObject` in "Volaapp\Base\ObservableObject.cs", and this name conflicts another type which has the same name from 'TodoScheduler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', you need to change the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found out I was performing a font size change operation on an array of labels that contained an image by accident.