# How to Rename ASP.Net MVC Project name in VisualStudio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried to Rename my project from **"ProTest"** to **"ProLive"**

I followed the instruction from the following [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195945/7734785).

After I rebuild When I run, I got the following error

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization;
Line 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 28:     using ProTest;
Line 29:     
Line 30:     

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ProLive\3ef330f9\ca7d7120\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.lnvurzvn.0.cs    Line: 28
```

> I tried to remove all **%temp%** files. and rebuild and rerun the application. Still same

Comment: you have using statement there that says ProTest, which you just renamed to ProLive.....

Comment: @Mahan.A everywhere it renamed to **ProLive** , this source file is creating on runtime. I don't know how to change it

Comment: Run a find all search at solution level for "ProTest" accessed via "Ctrl+Shift+F"

Comment: Goto build and Run all custom control and check whether references are getting updated

Comment: @Liamneesan, This link will help after attempting Samaritan_Learner's answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-broken-references?view=vs-2019
There is a section in the link called "Referenced file has been renamed"