# Move/rename project in Visual Studio 2008 with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Our team is developing a new product on the base of the old one and I received an honorable task of renaming old projects to the new name. For example:

- project OldProductLib.vcproj must become NewProductLib.vcproj
- \main\OldLib must become \main\NewLib

... and such.

Does anyone have a methodology and/or tool that would help me do this? What I'm looking for is a tool which will rename directory, update solution, *correctly* update TFS.

Comment: Best answer I've found for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10853509/10245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the projects in Visual Studio, and it'll fix up a lot of stuff for you.  It won't, however, fix the folder names.  Here's what I do when renaming a project.

1) Remove the project from the solution.
2) Rename the folder the project is in.
3) Re-add the project to the solution.
4) Rename the project in Visual Studio.

This will leave behind some items, like dlls with the old name in the bin folders.

Now, for the TFS problem.  I think when you add the projects back into the solution they will want to create new entries in TFS.  This probably isn't what you want.  I don't have a TFS available to me in order to test this right now, so I might have this part wrong, but I think if you were to update the "working folder" for a project between steps 2 and 3 it might hook it back up correctly.  Try this with a small sample solution before doing it with anything terribly important.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is possible but it is a painful experience. An easier option is to create a new project and branch everything into it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the TFS "Source Control Explorer" view for renaming.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in **Visual Studio 2012** and **Team Foundation Server 2012**. Take a look at [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17090927/280392), for a step-by-step guide on how to rename the project folder and keeping your TFS source control history for both the files and the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it in visual studio...

It can rename your project and I think creates the folders and the like for you.

Comment: Nope. Renamed a project in VS, but the file name stayed as-is. Same for

Comment: ... Same for folder - stayed as it was

Answer (score 0):

Renaming project folders in Visual Studio 2008 has [been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio), and the accepted solution was very useful to me.

Unfortunately, I am unable to help with TFS, but if you use Visual Studio to change the path to the project, perhaps it will handle the situation gracefully (one would expect it would).

Answer (score 0):

For the TFS part, I think you can use "Change Source Control" command at File->Source Control to rebind the projects after moving.