# Visual Studio: Tools to rename projects (and directories) automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, rename

Similar questions have been asked many times in SO. But most answers suggested to do it manually, which is very time consuming.

Any free tools that can rename projects (and directories) automatically?

[Filip Premanad Rydlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508299/filip-premanad-rydlo) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio/4507979#4507979) [Visual Studio Project Renamer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/vsrename.aspx), but it has not been updated since 2001.

[This tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ProjRename.aspx) can rename Visual C++ Projects. But my projects are mostly C#.

[CopyWiz](http://www.kinook.com/CopyWiz/) can `Rename an existing project; Fix up directories and filenames in your projects`, but it's costs 39 USD.

Similar questions:

- [How do I rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211241/how-do-i-rename-a-project-folder-from-within-visual-studio)
- [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Please add the [Visual Studio Project Renamer](http://normankosmal.com/wordpress/?page_id=15) to the list.It is not the same, you have mentioned. But as you said, that project is not updated since ages. Also, it runs only from the comand line. That got me to write a gui version, which basicly lets you rename projects directly from a gui. For now the tool supports Subversion (I will add support for GIT,HG and TFS soon).

Please check this [page](http://normankosmal.com/wordpress/?page_id=184) for more information.

Comment: Was for a week sorry for that. Its back up now.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I hate to "jump on the bandwagon", but I've found that creating my own little utility for this was the best route.  There are so many intricacies with a rename and project types.

I know it isn't the best thing, but overall it took me 20 minutes to write the utility and have been using it ever since.

Comment: VS 2017 seems to handle the renames ok now

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here looking for a solution:

I wrote an open-source cmdline utility that also deals with renaming in git so the history is not lost, moving to different directories etc.

Install via `dotnet tool install -g ModernRonin.ProjectRenamer`, see https://github.com/ModernRonin/ProjectRenamer for documentation.